# How to write C# code to retrieve value from SQL procedure and put it in text box in win form?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, stored-procedures

This is the output from SQL Stored Procedure.
[output_from_stored_procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfQ8Y.png)

Below is the form that I want to create. So I want to put the value in the second column from SQL procedure into the textbox below in windows form. For example, let say an integer value of 13 from Sum(LEAVE) column and row of EI01203 will be put in the the text box shown below.
[win_form_textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uB1p.png)

I have got the output from SQL procedure. However, I don't know how to proceed to the next step which is put the value in text box of win form. Pls help me suggest on that. Thank you.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Using a series of TextBoxes in this way is very inefficient.  Is there any reason that you do not want a DataGridView?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I will check into DataGridView. Because this is very new to me. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Steve Yes I have the sql stored procedure code but I have no idea how to put value in text_box while creating win form.

Comment: Pretty sure you can find here many answers that explain how to connect to a database, how to read data from a stored procedure and so on if you just try to search for these terms. But, if I understand correctly your level of knowledge of these techniques the best thing I can suggest is to read a dedicated tutorial about ADO.NET (the basic framework built by Microsoft to access data) One here for example https://dotnettutorials.net/course/ado-net-tutorial-for-beginners-and-professionals/

Comment: @Steve Thanks for the info. But could you pls guide me on how to read the data from sql stored procedure and show the read value in c# winform so that from that I can work on by myself?